# What is alternating current polarography (ACP)?

Tags: current

I am taking "RF Microwave Signal Chain & Network Analysis" webinar from Keysight. There is a slide there with acronym (ACP). I assumed it is alternating current polarography. I am attaching the slide.

Does anyone know what alternating current polarography (ACP) is?

I cannot find a good link online with good definition.

This has to do with testing and measuring electrical devices. Also, if someone could give an example, that would be great.

[image]

Comment: If you didn't invent the name, where did you hear it?

Comment: I am taking "RF Microwave Signal Chain & Network Analysis" webinar from Keysight. There is a slide there with acronym (ACP). I assumed it is alternating current polarography. I am attaching the slide.

Comment: OK, but can you list all the websites you have looked at that don't give you the information you want so that folk don't pointlessly stumble through your past and recent endeavours. Also, maybe you can have a think about this: what has your question got to do with electronic or electrical design? Maybe you should also speak with keysight to see what they say?

Comment: Andy, I think I answered my own question. According to the given link (https://www.rsc.org/publishing/journals/prospect/ontology.asp?id=CMO:0000033&MSID=b701017f)

Alternating current polarography

Definition: An electrochemical technique where the alternating current (ac) component of the cell current is measured as a function of time and as a function of the ac potential between the indicator and reference electrodes. The working electrode is a dropping mercury (or other liquid conductor) electrode and unstirred solutions are used.

Thank you for making me google harder!

Comment: Given the rest on that slide, I believe your google hit on Alternating current polargraphy is completely unrelated to the topic.

Comment: "Automatic Colt Pistol" has just as much to do with the other information in that slide as "Alternating Current Polarography." I almost suspect you are trolling us.

Comment: I would never...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that's a typo or an internal shortening.
Adjacent channel power ratio.
The ratio between the total power adjacent channel (intermodulation signal) to the main channel's power (useful signal).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacent_channel_power_ratio